# How to upload data from multiple view controllers to firebase database?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a multi view controller form in which at the end I would like to upload all the data from each view controller to my firebase database. I know one way to do it would be to pass data to the next view controller each time I press the next button with the prepareForSegue function, or I could upload the data in parts for every view controller. Is there a correct method for doing this, or is there another way to upload data from multiple view controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple forms for same process and uses same channel for upload then you can set data at the end. Because it creates only one request. Also another way of upload is suitable, But in all controller you have to pass same channel reference to upload data.

And, if in all controllers you are going to upload data to different channel, then it's better to handle on particular view controller.